# Error #1452 al intentar relacionar dos tablas

Tags: mysql

Intento relacionar dos tablas (usuarios y comentarios), la clave primaria de usuarios es idUsuario, y la clave foránea de la tabla comentarios es idUsuario.

> He especificado también las dos tablas como InnoDB.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Y en la siguiente imágen se comprueba la clave primaria y foránea de
>   la tabla comentarios.

[image]

> Al dirigirme al apartado de Diseñador y relacionar la clave primaria
>   IdUsuario (de la tabla usuarios) con la clave foránea IdUsuario (de la
>   tabla comentarios), aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe por qué aparece éste error y como podría solucionarse?

Comment: Me da que es que tienes registros en comentarios cuyo idUsuario no encuentra referenciado en Usuarios

Comment: Solucionado, parece ser que era eso. Entonces: ¿No se puede crear relaciones si ya hay registros introducidos ya en las tablas?

Comment: Se puede siempre y cuando se cumplan las restricciones de la relación.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se establecen restricciones de cualquier tipo en una o mas tablas, el motor verifica que las nuevas restricciones se cumplan para cada una de las filas de las tablas que intervienen.
  Seguramente tienes registros en tu tabla comentarios con un IdUsuario que no existe en la tabla Usuarios. Si realizas una limpieza de los datos de las tablas o generas el Usuario correspondiente para cada uno de los comentarios, no debería surgir éste Problema.