# Error al intentar crear relación entre tablas mysql

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando asociar user_id de mi tabla as_users a user_id de mi tabla pedido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recibo este desafortunado error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago click en crear relación y selecciono ambos datos y me aparece el error de arriba. ¿Podría ayudarme por favor? gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error #1452 al intentar relacionar dos tablas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201180/error-1452-al-intentar-relacionar-dos-tablas)

Comment: Lo que me viene en mente es que tengas algun trigger que se activa en una de las 2 tablas y esto te este causando un conflicto para poder relacionarlas